# Get content from html file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a list of html files. Each file repeatedly has the strings `onClick="rpd(SOME_NUMBER)"` . I know how to get the content from the html files, what I would want to do is get a list of the "SOME_NUMBER" . I saw that I might need to do a preg_match, but I'm horrible at regular expressions. I tried

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($url);    
$pattern= 'onClick="rpd(#);"';
preg_match($pattern, $file_content);
```

As you could imagine... it didn't work. What would be the best way to get this done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get it done:

```
    $file_content ='234=fdf donClick="rpd(5);"as23 f2 onClick="rpd(7);" dff fonClick="rpd(8);"';    
    $pattern= '/onClick="rpd\((\d+)\);"/';

    preg_match_all($pattern, $file_content,$matches);
    var_dump( $matches);
```

The output is like this:

```
    array (size=2)
    0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'onClick="rpd(5);"' (length=17)
      1 => string 'onClick="rpd(7);"' (length=17)
      2 => string 'onClick="rpd(8);"' (length=17)
    1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '8' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
preg_match('/onClick="rpd\((\d+)\);"/', $file_content,$matches);
print $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP, but the regular expression to match that would be:

```
'onClick="rpd\(([0-9]+)\)"'
```

Note that we need to escape those paranthesis with `\` because of their special meaning, also we surrounded our match with one regular paranthesis for seperating digits.

If `preg_match` also supports lookahead/lookbehind expressions:

```
 '(?<=onClick="rpd\()[0-9]+(?=\)")'
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_content='blah blah onClick="rpd(56)"; blah blah\nblah blah onClick="rpd(43)"; blah blah\nblah blah onClick="rpd(11)"; blah blah\n';
$pattern= '/onClick="rpd\((\d+)\)";/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $file_content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

That outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => onClick="rpd(56)";
            [1] => onClick="rpd(43)";
            [2] => onClick="rpd(11)";
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 56
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 11
        )

)
```

You can play around with my example here:  http://ideone.com/TzShPG

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this is to use DOMDocument and XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$ress= $xpath->query("//*[contains(@onclick,'rpd(')]/attribute::onclick");
foreach ($ress as $res) {
    echo substr($res->value,4,-1) . "\n";    
}
```